# using reduceByKey in pyspark for value with multiple fields

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I Have a key-value rdd that has the element form:

(key, ((v1, v2), 1))

I want to use `reduceByKey` to be able to gather for the same key the sum of all v1 and v2 respectively, and also add up all 1s all in the same index so the resulting reduced rdd has:

(key, ((sum_v1, sum_v2), sum_1s))

I tried several trials like:

```
.reduceByKey(lambda (p1,x), (p2,y) : (p1[0]+p2[0], p1[1]+p2[1]), x+y))
```

and other several trials similar to this but all in vain, I get 'x' is undefined and similar error commands..
what is the suitable function to use then??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of your value is: `((v1, v2), one)`

In order to reduce those 3 parameters try the following, which uses the parameters structure as `x` and `y` in `reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)`

```
.reduceByKey(lambda ((v1a,v2a),onea), ((v1b,v2b),oneb) : ((v1a+v1b,v2a+v2b),onea+oneb) )
```

Comment: yes, I had tried a similar format too. It works now, guess it was a VM error. Thanks!!